# Issue with cert-manager installation

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

I am getting errors as below

```
unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: resource mapping not found for name: "argocd-server" namespace: "argocd" from "": no matches for kind "Certificate" in version "cert-manager.io/v1"
│ ensure CRDs are installed first
```

The Terraform config is below.

```
data "http" "cert-manager-crds" {
  count = var.enable_argocd ? 1 : 0
  url   = "https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.13.3/cert-manager.crds.yaml"
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "cert-manager-crds" {
  count     = var.enable_argocd ? 1 : 0
  yaml_body = data.http.cert-manager-crds[count.index].response_body
}

module "argocd" {
  count  = var.enable_argocd ? 1 : 0
  source = "../argocd"

  azure_resource_group_name = data.terraform_remote_state.shared.outputs.resourcegroup.name[0]
  cluster_name              = data.terraform_remote_state.aks.outputs.aks.cluster_name[0]
  description               = "ArgoCD"
  env_name                  = var.env_name
  name                      = data.terraform_remote_state.aks.outputs.aks.cluster_name[0]
  region                    = var.azure_region
  tags                      = {}
  vpc_tags                  = ""
  depends_on = [kubectl_manifest.cert-manager-crds]
}
```

The Terraform code to deploy helm charts is here.

```
https://gist.github.com/ameyaagashe/b8e835758ae378db6a168d57127464f2
```

I did few combinations but failing to get helm charts deployed.

Comment: when reading the error message, what do you think is the problem?

Comment: CRDs are not getting installed.

Comment: the error says that the CRD needs to be install *first*. Meaning, you cant create both CRD and CR in the same apply operation,

Comment: So what is wrong and what needs to be done to resolve the issue. depends_on condition is not working

Comment: you cannot do it in a single apply operation. In your case you need to apply cert manager first, and then the rest. Terraform will scan the cluster upon apply, if the crd is not there while something depends on it, it errors. It doesnt know it will be created through some helm release.